# how do I call legendPath

Tags: dynamic, openlayers, legend

```
var landcoverLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    id: 'landcover',
    title: 'Landcover 2010',
    visible: false,
    legendPath:'nepal:Landcover',
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://db2map.gistemp.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
        hidpi: false,
        params: { 'VERSION': '1.1.1', 'LAYERS': 'nepal:Landcover' },
        serverType: 'geoserver'

    })
});
```

Comment: It's hard to understand your question. What do you want to do? Add a WMS layer to map?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are requesting **GetLegendGraphic** from Geoserver. The request is like below:

```
var landcoverLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
    id: 'landcover',
    title: 'Landcover 2010',
    visible: false,
    legendPath:'http://db2map.gistemp.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=nepal:Landcover',
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
        url: 'http://db2map.gistemp.com/geoserver/gwc/service/wms',
        hidpi: false,
        params: { 'VERSION': '1.1.1', 'LAYERS': 'nepal:Landcover' },
        serverType: 'geoserver'

    })
});
```

Here is the reference in Geoserver docs: 
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/index.html